# Kubernetes service account with cluster role

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I have created a service account with cluster role, is it possible to deploy pods across different namespaces with this service account through APIs?

Below is the template from which the role creation and binding is done:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: api-access
rules:
  -
    apiGroups:
      - ""
      - apps
      - autoscaling
      - batch
      - extensions
      - policy
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    resources:
      - componentstatuses
      - configmaps
      - daemonsets
      - deployments
      - events
      - endpoints
      - horizontalpodautoscalers
      - ingress
      - jobs
      - limitranges
      - namespaces
      - nodes
      - pods
      - persistentvolumes
      - persistentvolumeclaims
      - resourcequotas
      - replicasets
      - replicationcontrollers
      - serviceaccounts
      - services
    verbs: ["*"]
  - nonResourceURLs: ["*"]
    verbs: ["*"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: api-access
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: api-access
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: api-service-account
  namespace: default
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your question. What do you mean "through APIs?" What exactly are you trying to do / have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your service account will be able to create and act on resources in any namespace because a you've granted it these permissions at the cluster scope using a `ClusterRoleBinding`.